# SKSMTPMessage Error- The operation couldn't be completed.(OSStatus error -9807.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, smtp

Can anyone please help me to understand the error- “**The operation couldn't be completed.(OSStatus error -9807.)**”.

I googled & found, except `SkSMTPMessage`, sometimes this error comes in `AVAudioPlayer` class but the number is different i.e. **9800**.

My questions are, **A)** would you please tell, what is significant of number here, **B)** why such error occurs in code?

I found one *solution* here-

It seems there are some compatability issues with iOS 5+ or later and this smtp app because iOS started using TLS 1.2.

find the source in the `SKPSMTPMessage.m`, and modify the source like following, it works

```
//CFDictionarySetValue(sslOptions, kCFStreamSSLLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1); 
CFDictionarySetValue(sslOptions, kCFStreamSSLLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv3);
```

It didn’t work in my case.

In the case, when i tried to **send email with my `gmail` account it worked**, but when I tried to send it from my companies `SMTP` credentials, it didn’t work.

How can I solve such issue from my app?

Answer (score 2):

It might be caused by SSL certificate. I have encountered the same issue and it turned out that my server is using self-signed SSL certificate and iOS has trouble with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
// Only do this for self-signed certs!
emailMessage.validateSSLChain = NO;
```